# Ordering a queryset by score in a many-to-many relationship of another model

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have models setup as follows, each lesson belongs to a chapter and has a owner. For each chapter, the user has a score which is stored in the `UserChapterScore` table

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Chapter(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Lesson(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.TextField()

 class UserChapterScore(models.Model):
     chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

How can I retrieve lessons belonging to a chapter, ordered by the owner's chapter score?

EDIT: Please convert to M2M equivalents if needed. I used the models to illustrate the structure of the models

Comment: Two questions: 1. The user score is unique for each chapter? 2. Or is better to have a score for each lesson and the chapter is the sum of all the lesson scores?

Comment: 1. Yes, the user score is unique for each chapter, 2. having a per lesson score is ok, but in that case, the aggregate score of all lessons belonging to that user in that chapter must be used to order the lessons

Comment: So, what I can see a lesson score is better than a chapter score. Then you can do an aggregate to use for lessons by user scores order. Right? Tell me and I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course can, you can try with this...

```
from django.db import models

class Chapter(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

    def get_lessons(self):
        """return all lessions filtered by specific chapter"""
        return Lesson.objects.filter(chapter__pk=self.pk)


class Lesson(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.TextField()

    def get_user_chapters(self):
        """return all chapters by specific `chapter` and `user` in this lession"""
        return UserChapterScore.objects.filter(chapter=self.chapter, user=self.owner)

    def get_user_scores(self):
        """return total scores by specific `chapter` and `user` in this lession"""
        return self.get_user_chapters().aggregate(models.Sum('score'))['score__sum']


class UserChapterScore(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Update, you can each it;

```
lessons = [{
    'lessons': chapter.get_lessons(), # return queryset of lessons
    'lessons_detail': [
        {
            'owner': c.owner, 
            'scores': c.get_user_scores(),
            'chapters': c.get_user_chapters()
        } for c in chapter.get_lessons()
    ]
} for chapter in Chapter.objects.all()]
```

Comment: I don't see a query to get lessons sorted by the owner's chapter score anywhere

Answer (score 0):

For [backward relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) you can use `<lowercase_related_model_name>_set` to get the related model. For your example, you can try this:

```
Lesson.objects.fitler(chapter=chapter).order_by('chapter__userchapterscore_set__score')
```

Answer (score 0):

This was simpler than I thought. I needed a join between `Lesson`, `User` and `UserChapterScore` such that

- the lesson's chapter is the chapter for which I want the list
- the lesson owner id and the User id join the `User` and `Lesson` table
- the `UserChapterScore` table's chapter should be the same as the chapter for which I want the list
- the `UserChapterScore` table and `User` table join by the user id in both tables.

I didn't realise that Django does when we use the double underscore notation in queryset filters.

Also, the reverse accessor for the `UserChapterScore` table exists as `userchapterscore` in the `User` model, in the case of foreign keys.

The final query is:

```
Lesson.objects.filter(chapter=chapter, owner__userchapterscore__chapter=chapter).order_by('owner__userchapterscore__score)
```